# ¿Por que datetimepicker funciona en google crome y en Mozilla firefox no?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, datepicker, firefox

Este código me funciona al llamar un input y despliega la fecha en chrome pero en firefox no funciona:

```
<div class='input-group date'>
   <input  type='text' id="date_ex" name="date_emi" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                </span>
            </span>
</div>

$(function () {
  $(".date").datetimepicker({
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
    view: 'years',
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
   });
});
```

Al dar `f12` en [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) no aparece nada pero en [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) aparece el siguente error

> jQuery.Deferred exception: (intermediate value).toString(...).split(...)[1] is undefined Datetimepicker

Comment: ¿En la consola "F12" aparece algún error?

Comment: sii aparece esto en crome no aparece ningun error

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception: (intermediate value).toString(...).split(...)[1] is undefined

Datetimepicker@http://especial.transporteskj.com/default/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:112:29
$.fn.datetimepicker/<@http://especial.transporteskj.com/default/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:1400:46
.each@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2:2811
r.prototype.each@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2:1001

Comment: @FechoJerez, por favor, actualiza la pregunta con la descripción del error. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

podrías poner la parte en donde agregar las librerías a tu HTML.

Yo tengo las siguientes de manera local

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Y lo agrego de la siguiente manera:

```
$(".fecha").datepicker();
     $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: 'Anterior',
        nextText: 'Siguiente',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        firstDay: 7,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
} );
```

Comment: Por lo visto en los comentarios, la pregunta se enfoca a bootstrap datetimepicker y no al de jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que el id o la clase que ocupas en el input sea el mismo que ocupas en el script ya que en el script pones

```
$(".date")
```

Siendo que no existe un date en el html que nos muestras

```
<div class='input-group date'>
   <input  type='text' id="date_ex" name="date_emi" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                </span>
            </span>
</div>
```